# What is the difference between Reinforment Learning and Sequential Pattern Mining?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am kind of confused with sequential pattern mining and reinforcement learning. I just want to know the difference between sequential pattern mining and reinforcement learning. With sequential pattern mining, I can find all the sequential states, then why would I need Reinforcement Learning?

Sequential pattern mining finds patterns with frequencies in the data and tells which sequence is more probable but how does Reinforcement Learning find the best way to the goal?

Comment: Your question asks about the difference between "sequential pattern mining" and "reinforcement learning." Can you edit your post to include a definition of "sequential pattern mining," and a citation to a book, article or other resource about this topic? The answers to your question will crucially hinge on what this unusual term means.